# Background x-repeat negative margin for overlap

Tags: css, background, margins

Actually my first question on stack:)

I'm trying to get a negative (right) margin on my repeating background, so there won't be a gap between the repeating images.

It seems there is no css syntax for this.

To make things clear, i added an image below. So i'm trying to get the repeating images of the cookie-like things to overlap so there's no gap between them.

[screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5IN2.png)

Comment: Jep this can't be done with css, but you might actually get it working if you give each image an element. Then there are lots of possibillities to achieve this. Anyway modifying the image would be the best solution I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply multiple backgrounds to an element, so why not use this background image twice, with different horizontal offsets.

```css
body {
  min-height:170px;
  background:
    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKAKB.png') 0 100% repeat-x,
    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKAKB.png') 75px 100% repeat-x;
}
```

PS the cookie like things are called kruidnoten. Although everybody calls then pepernoten, which is not actually true.

Comment: Thanks, that's the workaround i was looking for. My clients are very pleased with the kruidnoten on their website. Groeten!