# HTML or CSS code to repeat properly skew pattern

Tags: html, css

I have a pattern, that i would like to use on my website as background, that has skew shape. I wonder if there is an HTML or CSS code to shift second background closer to the left, to hide white get and make it look better. Thank you in advance.

**skew pattern**
[image]

Comment: `background-repeat: repeat`?

Comment: yes, but do you see blank space? is there a way to move next rep closer to first image?

Comment: share you code so we can help you

Comment: i'm using standard background-repeat, but i hope there is a way to use something like padding with -100px value or smth like that

Comment: show us your code, we cannot help with only an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new image that is shifted horizontally so you have rectangle pattern. I created image <del>but it is not as good as it can be because I do not have original.</del>you can use it.

**Your new image is here**

[image: You new image is here]

```css
div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvap7.png);
}
```

```html
<div style=width:1000px;height:1000px></div>
```

---

## Instructions to create the image

I use program GIMP (http://gimp.org/). It is free.

1. Remove white area (make it transparent) using *Fuzzy Select Tool* and Delete key. If transparency is not enabled, right-click the layer and enable it.
2. Duplicate the image (Ctrl-C, then Ctrl-V)
3. Move it using *Move* horizontally so there is no transparent area between the two copies.
4. Press Ctrl-H (*anchor the floating layer*)
5. Right-click the top layer and *Merge Down*
6. Crop the image (*Image→Autocrop Image*)
7. Crop it to the center (*Image→Canvas size…*), set width 264 (width of one “block”) and then click *Center* button
8. Manually remove white pixels
9. Export it as PNG (in *File* menu)
10. Use it

Comment: That's look great! What did you do to shift it horizontally?

Comment: Thanks again! interesting solution. But you don't know if something exists in html/css coding to overlap background images? make distance shorter between them?

Comment: I think you can't if you use repeating. You can overlap limited number of images. But when want to you use `background-repeat`, you can (probably) always solve it this way.

Comment: I think i found my answer here: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593296/background-x-repeat-negative-margin-for-overlap)

Comment: @AntonChuikin Yes. This is for repeating two different images (as “layers”).